# Question about the Playfair cipher

Tags: encryption, playfair

The task:

> The Playfair cipher with $I = J, X$  added into two same letters and
> the key ***keep distance**.*

The plaintext:

> CORONAVIRUS SPREADS FAST

> The whitespaces in plaintext and key are to be discarded.

not sure what they mean by I = J, X

The table

[image]

I am not quite sure what they are asking for. I know that you usally remove letter *J* and replace it by *I*,   But now it says * I = J,X" what does he mean by that?

This is what I've written as "coronavirus spreads fast"

**CO RO NA VI RU SX SP RE AD SF AS TX**

Comment: Do you know what is a comma and [description of the Playfair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Playfair_cipher#Description)?

Comment: Yeah my bad, looks like I just was a bit confused by the sentence how it was written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means any instances of double letters in encryption are split up by injecting a letter x (as well as the usual I = J).

In other words read the instructions as

- I=J
- X added into two same letters
- Key KEEP DISTANCE